# Apollo graphql use enums as variables in useQuery with typescript

Tags: typescript, enums, graphql, apollo-client

I want to use enums in an input type but it comes out as a string which errors out in the query.

schema:

```
 type Query {
    interiors(filter: InteriorsFilterInput): [Interior]
  }

  input InteriorsFilterInput {
    productId: Int!
    type: InteriorType!
  }
```

typescript generated types with apollo-tools:

```js
export enum InteriorType {
  POSTER = "POSTER",
  WALLPAPER = "WALLPAPER",
}
```

And the query in typescript looks like this:

```js
const QUERY = gql`
  query GetProductInteriors($productId: Int!, $type: InteriorType) {
    interiors(
      filter: { productId: $productId, type: $type }
    ) {
      id
    }
  }
`;

export interface IProductkeywords {
  product: GetProduct_product;
}

const ProductInteriors: React.FC<IProductkeywords> = ({ product }) => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery<GetProductInteriors>(QUERY, {
    variables: {
      productId: parseInt(product.id),
      type: InteriorType.POSTER,
    },
  });

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <AutoHeightCard>
      <CardHeader title="Interiors"></CardHeader>
      <CardContent>Interiors here</CardContent>
    </AutoHeightCard>
  );
};
```

Inpecting the query in devtools I see that the type is sent in as a string.

```
variables: {productId: 73803, type: "POSTER"}
```

How do I do to make it the gql enum type (without quotation marks)?

Btw, I've tried also replacing `type: InteriorType.POSTER` with `type: InteriorType[InteriorType.POSTER]` without success

Comment: it's sent as string just to be json valid ? with type it won't be valid

Comment: No, not for enums

Comment: it's a limitation, from js env - variables is an object and its prop value can't be an abstract (to js) literal (possibly conflicting) ... what problems/errors do you have with enum values passed as strings? should be/usually accepted/expected format